# How can we handle cy.stub() inside a loop

Tags: cypress, stub

Currently when I am using cy.stub() inside a loop, It works for the first time but for the second time it throws error "Attempted to wrap open which is already wrapped".
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h74d9.png)

```js
for(...){
   cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.stub(win, 'open').as('popup');
    })
    //click event that opens the window
    cy.get("@popup").should("be.called"); // works for the first loop and breaks for the second time
}
```

Comment: Hi. Created stubs are automatically reset between tests, so as long as your loop does not create separate tests, you have to explicitly reset them after each iteration: `stub.reset()`, so you will avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Move the stub setup outside the loop

```js
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('popup');
})
for(...){
  //click event that opens the window
  cy.get("@popup").should("be.called"); 
}
```

Comment: Yes.. I missed moving it outside the loop, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a stub with the same exact alias each time in your loop. Each alias should be unique and to do that with your loop you'll have to append a unique id to it.

```js
for(i=0, i<10, i++){
   cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.stub(win, 'open').as(`popup${i}`);
    })
    //click event that opens the window
    cy.get(`@popup${i}`).should("be.called"); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, It still shows the same error as 'Attempted to wrap open which is already wrapped'